# SceneKit Rig and Animate Custom Geometry with SCNSkinner

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

The setup: I have a character that is made up of different Blender objects (`head` is a separate geometry object, `upperBody` is a separate geometry object, `legs` are a different geometry object, etc) which I each import into my SceneKit Scene from different sources via:

```
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(head)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(upperBody)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(legs)
```

What I want to do is flatten all those different objects into one geometry object named `model` using

```
let model = scene.rootNode.flattenedClone()
```

So far so good. My scene now only has one childNode named `model`. I also have a rig exported from Blender. Is it possible to add this rig to my `model` using `SCNSkinner` and to manipulate its geometry, and if so - how can this be achieved?

Comment: As far as I know, any animatable "obect or character" needs its own rig that must be included within the file you export from Blender. I usually use DAE (Collada). All Geo-Objects  must be organised within its own scene-graf, the node hierarchy. This file then you load into a SCNNode. You can then use separate animation files with SCNAnimation that moves the Rig on the Main File. Never make a flattenedClone from the orig animated model, it will not work. Flattened Clones are for other purposes, surch as reducing draw calls when rendering complex objects. Use it for static geometry.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So what if - let's say - I create a somewhat complex object using the SceneKit Editor using boxes, cylinders, spheres (etc) - is there a way to create a rig for this one and animate the geometry based on that rig? Or in other words - is there a way to do any object manipulation for objects that do not have the rig included in the blender file?

Comment: If you have a scene file containing objects, the only animation you can do is moving the individual Objects in the scene, rotate or change their size. (add physics bodies, etc...) If you want to animate something in the way of geometry defomation. lika a human character, you need a correct rig on that geometry. I never seen creation of a rig out of the box using the scene editor or directly in code. (In my opinion, that's way too hard). Better let tools like Bllender do the heavy lifting of rigging a geometry. Use scenekit to hold the scene and use it to render and control the stuff.